# Why is my Gitlab shell executor only returning "0 0"?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, build-pipeline, shell-script

All the sudden my self-hosted runner set to use the shell executor started returning "0 0" which is causing the pipeline to incorrectly "succeed" at every step without executing the commands in the pipeline.

```
Running with gitlab-runner 15.9.1 (d540b510)
on runner.my.domain DFy6JND6, system ID: s_e0fd8a656439
Preparing the "shell" executor
00:00
Using Shell (bash) executor...
Preparing environment
00:00
Running on runner.my.domain...
Getting source from Git repository
00:01
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/gitlab-runner/builds/DFy6JND6/0/mygitlab/myrepo/.git/
Checking out 99ba9c4f as detached HEAD (ref is develop)...
Removing --version.hwm
Removing --version.pwd
Removing --version.pwi
Removing validate.hwm
Removing validate.pwd
Removing validate.pwi
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:01
$ packer --version
0 0
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.pkr.hcl' -print0 | xargs -t0n1 packer validate
packer validate ./rocky8.pkr.hcl
0 0
packer validate ./rocky9.pkr.hcl
0 0
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
Job succeeded
```

If I go in and login as the user gitlab-runner and go to the folder the runner is running and type those same commands (same shell) I get this:

```
[gitlab-runner@runner]$ packer --version
1.8.6
[gitlab-runner@runner]$ packer validate ./rocky8.pkr.hcl
The configuration is valid.
[gitlab-runner@runner]$ packer validate ./rocky9.pkr.hcl
The configuration is valid.
```

The pipeline was running fine before I'm not sure what I've changed.

In case anyone's curious here's the whole pipeline:

```yaml
before_script:
  - packer --version

stages:
  - validate
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

validate:
  stage: validate
  script:
    - find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.pkr.hcl' -print0 | xargs -t0n1 packer validate

build:
  stage: deploy
  environment: production
  script:
    - find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.pkr.hcl' -print0 | xargs -t0n1 packer validate
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      when: on_success
```

and here's the runner config:

```ini
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0
shutdown_timeout = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "runner.my.domain"
  url = "https://gitlab.com/"
  id = 21590649
  token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  token_obtained_at = 2023-03-05T02:09:32Z
  token_expires_at = 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
  executor = "shell"
  shell = "bash"
  [runners.cache]
    MaxUploadedArchiveSize = 0
```

I'm still pretty new to the self-hosted runner and relatively new to Gitlab. Any thoughts?

EDIT: installed the runner on an identical machine and had the same problem. here's some additional environmental info:

```
[gitlab-runner@runner ~]$ uname -a
Linux runner.xtal.in 5.14.0-162.18.1.el9_1.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Feb 9 04:28:41 EST 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

[gitlab-runner@runner ~]$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 9.1 (Plow)

[gitlab-runner@runner ~]$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.1.8(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

[gitlab-runner@runner ~]$ gitlab-runner --version
Version:      15.9.1
Git revision: d540b510
Git branch:   15-9-stable
GO version:   go1.18.10
Built:        2023-02-20T21:03:05+0000
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```